# Webview Html button calling back to Android to run function or SetContentView

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Basically i want to be able to click a button in the webview that can do 2 things

1. change my SetContentView
2. Run my Camera Routine  that i have already made in Android ( i want to run the android code i made run in android)

Currently all sources i found only seem to be related to opening a filechooser but i just want to be able to run my camera code i have made in Android or Change my SetContentView   eg  SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Menu2);

The problem is using JavaScript I'm finding that it will not allow me to Execute SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Menu2) or anything  outside of the MainActivity as a call back

I really hope someone can help

Comment: This site is all about asking questions. You don't have to apologies for seeking help. You should go straight to the point. You are also encouraged to give more context in the form of code snippets you've already tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is using JavaScript I'm finding that it will not allow me to Execute SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Menu2) or anything outside of the MainActivity as a call back

The problem is `SetContentView` needs to be executed on the UI Thread. So you need to use [Activity.RunOnUiThread](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.App.Activity.RunOnUiThread/p/Java.Lang.IRunnable/) for that:

```
public class MyJSInterface:Java.Lang.Object
{
    Activity context;
    public MyJSInterface(Activity c)
    {
        context = c;
    }
    [Export]
    [JavascriptInterface]
    public void MyCallback()
    {
        //run the SetContentView on the UI Thread
        context.RunOnUiThread(() => {
            context.SetContentView(Resource.Layout.NewLayout);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: O my. thank you so much! that is exactly what i needed, thank you sir!

Comment: If the answer is what you want. Could you please mark it as answer :D